# puma gem - Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: puma

I was getting the following error while installing puma gem

```
    $ gem install puma
    Fetching: puma-2.11.2.gem (100%)
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing puma:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    ruby extconf.rb
    checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
    checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Answer (score 77):

Try the following

```
gem install puma -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
bundle install
```

You can also specify the gem version, like the following:

```
gem install puma -v '2.11.3' -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Comment: I'm on El Capitian OSX 10.11.2. When I first did `gem install puma` - it gave me `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension`. I then tried your send command (with puma version "2.9.1") and it seems to have worked with no errors! (yay!). Please would you be able to explain what this command mean? (I'm curious now as to why this command solves the problem). Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Worked for me on El Capitan, no idea why though.

Comment: install special version of puma that what i needed exactly

Comment: On El Capitan, run `gem install puma -v '2.11.2' -- --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl`. This works fine for me.

Comment: `gem install puma -v '3.6.0' -- --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl` worked on  seirra

Comment: I'm also on El Capitan and ran @KevinR. solution. worked for me too. Although I would like to know why in this specific OS that worked and how

Comment: Thanks @mahi, I'm on El Captain and this worked like a charm. Cheers m8!

Comment: gem install puma -v '3.6.0' -- --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl 
worked for me on MacOSX 10.14.3 (18D109)

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2304#issuecomment-664448309) on [this issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2304) helped me install 4.3.5 on Big Sur. 

`gem install puma -v '4.3.5' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`

Answer (score 41):

I'm on OS X 10.12.4 and the comment @mahi added worked for me:

```
gem install puma -v '3.6.0' -- --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```

Comment: @Ameen what isn't working? Are you getting the same error as above or a different error? Also note this is for OS X 10.12.4 not Ubuntu. There is a good chance the openssl library is somewhere else in Ubuntu.

Comment: Worked for OSX 10.12.6 (Sierra), `bundle install` is now successful.

Comment: Omg this is what i needed. Worked on macOS 10.14.3

Answer (score 22):

Not my answer but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63278694/thin-and-puma-fail-with-similar-issues-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-exten) helped me install puma on macos (big sur) since there were warnings when building puma.

The command that I used is this:

```
gem install puma -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Comment: This is the solution. Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63201544/4843137

Answer (score 19):

libssl1.0-dev installing helped to me. Try

```
apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

and then

```
gem install puma
```

Comment: Or `apt install libssl-dev` for a more generic dev version.

Comment: This is a working solution for Ubuntu/Linux developers

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks @Victor

Comment: Yes, This is working in Ubuntu 18.04, Thank You so much

Comment: this helped me resolve this error on Windows Linux Subsystem using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried

```
DISABLE_SSL=true gem install puma
```

Specify the version if you have version specific requirement like:

```
DISABLE_SSL=true gem install puma -v version_number
```

Comment: That's the easiest solution if we are talking development environment!

Answer (score 13):

I had similar issue on OSx El Capitan. In order to fix the issue I had to do:

```
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
```

Comment: This will may trigger a warning and will not work
```Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib```

Answer (score 9):

It could be an open ssl error

```
gem install puma -v 2.11.2 -- --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```

Answer (score 8):

I've run into a similar error under Mac OS X 10.10.

Details in the `mkmf.log` showed that this was due to:

> Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please
>   re-run as root via sudo.

Which was caused by the installation of a new version of Xcode.
This was easily solved by accepting the Xcode license from Apple:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Hope this might help someone in the future ;-)

Answer (score 8):

When using bundler and homebrew:

```
$ bundle config build.puma --with-cppflags=-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include
$ bundle install
```

I copied and adapted this answer from [Lloeki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368409/lloeki) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31516586/704499

Comment: This was a lifesaver for me! Had this issue on Mac OS 10.14.5 with Puma 4.0.1. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The gem is looking for ssl libraries. So we have to provide the path to the lib containing the ssl lib

e.g. /usr/share/openssl

In my case the the ssl lib "libcrypto" was in /usr/local/lib. So let's pass /usr/local to it (excluding **lib** word).

For gem install

```
gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=/usr/local
```

For bundle install

```
bundle config build.puma --with-opt-dir=/usr/local
bundle install
```

notice the name build.**puma**. where **puma** is the name of the gem.

The build config command adds the following to ~/.bundle/config

```
---
BUNDLE_BUILD__PUMA: "--with-opt-dir=/usr/local"
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to do this beforehand:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

Comment: I tried ```sudo apt-get install libssl-dev``` then installed ```gem install puma -v '3.1.0'``` but it didn't worked. Then I ```sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev``` then installed gem it worked. Thanks @matsko

Answer (score 3):

For puma `6.0` and above use the following

```bash
PUMA_DISABLE_SSL=1 gem install puma -v "6.2.1"
```

If you're facing issue with `bundle install`

Run

```bash
export PUMA_DISABLE_SSL=1 

bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `brew info openssl` and follow the instructions there. Do not try to `--force` link the latest openssl with the one that comes installed with OSX by default. (0.9.8)

Specifically it'll ask you to add the Homebrew version of openssl (should be 1.0.2 as of this date) into your $PATH.
`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Note: Make sure to remove any `export PATH` lines from the bash_profile, since this line above exports it for you appending the rest of the $PATH variable to the end. To view the bash profile use `vi ~/.bash_profile`

This fixed the problems for installing ruby gems that require compilation. (Puma in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Install these packages.

```
apt-get install openssl ruby-openssl libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic, but nothing here helped, so I am sharing how i fixed this, since it took a lot of digging a bit of reading.

re-isntall open ssl:
`brew reinstall openssl`

get the path to the installed openssl: `brew --prefix openssl`

finally, reinstall puma with the correct path 
`gem install puma -v '5.6.7' -- --with-openssl-dir=/path/to/openssl`

finally if you using bundle, you can go ahead and `bundle install/update`