# gem eventmachine fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, homebrew, eventmachine

Just installed El Capitan and can't install gem `eventmachine` `1.0.7`. `openssl` is at `1.0.2a-1`. Tried to use `--with-ssl-dir` but it seems ignored.

Reported it to their [github repo](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/602) as well.

Any suggestions are really appreciated. Thanks.

```
$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2a-1/include/openssl/ssl.h
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2a-1/include/openssl/ssl.h

$ gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.7' -- --with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2a-1/include
/Users/pain/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150612-56154-1hsjz2n.rb extconf.rb --with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2a-1/include
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue... yes
checking for clock_gettime()... no
checking for gethrtime()... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling binder.cpp
In file included from binder.cpp:20:
./project.h:116:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 581, accepted):

```
$ gem install eventmachine -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include                                                                                                             
Building native extensions with: '--with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed eventmachine-1.0.8
1 gem installed
```

You can also set up bundler like this but I think that is superficial

```
bundle config build.eventmachine --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Comment: For me, I had to install openssl first before this worked. e.g. `brew install openssl`.

Comment: If you have your gems set to a specific directory in your repo, i.e. `vendor/bundle` then you will want to run the `bundle config build.GEMNAME--with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include`. I had to run the same thing with the gem `puma` so I imagine this is happening for other gems as well.

Comment: see answer with: 'bundle config build.eventmachine --with-cppflags=-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include' from lloeki. That worked for me. Not this one.

Comment: This worked for me `gem install eventmachine -v 1.0.8 -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include` on OSX El Capitan 10.11.5

Comment: for me after install `brew install openssl` I have to do `brew link openssl --force`

Comment: `gem install eventmachine -- --with-cppflags=-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include`

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I had the problem with eventmachine 1.2.7 installation and this resolved it.

Comment: `-with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include` this save me on Ubuntu 20.4. Before that system always ignore openssl dir options . Thanks bro.

Comment: Works on Windows 10 for me

Comment: `gem install eventmachine -v 1.2.7 -- --with-cppflags=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include` works for me on Mac Silicon

Comment: ^ worked for me too, needed to escape the '@' in bash fyi

Answer (score 265):

When using bundler and homebrew:

```
$ bundle config build.eventmachine --with-cppflags=-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include
$ bundle install
```

Comment: For me, I had to install openssl first before this worked.  e.g.  `brew install openssl`

Comment: This version worked for me to install eventmachine 1.0.3 on top of ruby 2.1.2

Comment: Fantastic! This is also the way to go for other gems (e.g. puma) that depend on openssl

Comment: I think this answer is better than the approved one, because since it uses `bundle install` to perform the actual gem installation, it guarantees you'll install the exact version specified in your bundle. The accepted answer will install the latest version, unless you include the `-v x.x.x` in the `gem install` command manually.

Answer (score 127):

```
brew link --force openssl
```

Then:

```
gem install eventmachine
```

It also fixes:

- gem install taks
- bundle install
- rake and rails tasks

P.S. Probably you'll need to remove and run `brew install openssl` again

The issue happends because Apple had removed openssl from OSX (in El Captain build)

Comment: This was indeed the fix on El Capitan.

Comment: For clarification, what is the order of brew remove/install/link

Comment: @Abram In case of `brew link --force openssl` had no effect. Then do `brew uninstall openssl`, `brew install openssl`, `brew link --force openssl`

Comment: This is the answer on a Mac today (El Capitan, 2015-2016). EDIT: Just forcing the brew openssl. I didn't need to specify a version of EventMachine (I was installing Middleman).

Comment: Worked for me as well. Good call.

Comment: Worked for me, BigSur 2022.

Answer (score 19):

```
gem pristine eventmachine -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

pristine removes the old gem and recompiles it.

The cpp flags option allows the compiler to find the openssl headers.

If you prefer to abstract away the cpp flags argument, you can do the following:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib/pkgconfig"
```

You can also add the version if you like:

```
gem pristine eventmachine -v '1.0.4' -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Comment: why `pristine` instead of `install`?

Comment: `gem install eventmachine -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include` worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

I was trying to install v 1.0.3 and this worked for me.

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3' -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

These discussions were very helpful: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/602

*This assumes the machine already has openssl installed via `brew`.*

Comment: You need a hypen before `I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include`. It's one character so stackoverflow doesn't let me edit it

Comment: Fixed it @MaicolBen

Answer (score 9):

This solved the problem for me:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib/pkgconfig" gem install eventmachine -v "1.0.8"
```

Source: https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/254

Comment: Unecessarily complicated, why not just set the var: export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$( brew --prefix openssl )/lib/pkgconfig # now you can install any packages, add to .bashrc, or what you use

Answer (score 8):

If you're installing EventMachine as a dependency of another gem, be sure to specify the correct version when you manually install the gem:

```
gem install eventmachine -v 1.0.5 -- --with-cppflags=-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include
```

Then you can install the gem that you were originally trying to install:

```
gem install mailcatcher
```

Answer (score 8):

This looks like a more recent issue: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/936

I solved this problem on macOS `12.3.1` with the following:

M1 Max:

```
gem install eventmachine -- --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1n/
```

Intel:

```
gem install eventmachine -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1n/
```

Comment: I had to change the `.../openssl@1.1/1.1.1n` to `1.1.1q`.

Comment: And I had to go with `1.1.1s`

Answer (score 5):

One alternative is to add a bundler config entry for your whole user profile, like this:

```
cd ~
bundle config build.eventmachine --with-cppflags=-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include
```

it'll create a .bundle/config file in your home directory, which is then used in all your projects when you run `bundle install`.

Comment: Lovely and still works on an M1 MBP and Ruby 3.x.

Answer (score 5):

I met the same eventmachine issue and the answers above didn't work for me, finally reinstall ruby with given openssl version works:

```
rvm reinstall 3.1.2 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me -

```
    gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.7' -- --debug --backtrace --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    Building native extensions with: '--debug --backtrace --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib'
    This could take a while...
    Successfully installed eventmachine-1.0.7
    Parsing documentation for eventmachine-1.0.7
    Installing ri documentation for eventmachine-1.0.7
    Done installing documentation for eventmachine after 9 seconds
    1 gem installed
```

**NOTE:-** Before I was able to successfully install this gem, I had to do a few things. These might apply to you, so listing them here -

1.) got off the corporate-VPN 
    OR you might have to turn ON proxy settings

2.) PKG_CONFIG_PATH was set to -

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig
```

3.) had to add the following to $PATH in bash_profile (in my case ~/.zshrc)

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
```

4.) Also note, that contrary to some answers I got in this SO post, and also this thread on [github-eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/602), I was not able to install `eventmachine`

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.7' -- --debug --backtrace --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/include --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib
Fetching: eventmachine-1.0.7.gem (100%)
Building native extensions with: '--debug --backtrace --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/include --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

It seems `/usr/local/opt/openssl/include` is the right location and not `/usr/local/include` when specifying the openssl location.

Comment: This miraculously worked for me, after trying most of the other suggestions, I just had to edit the version from `1.0.7` to `1.2.7`.

Comment: This also worked for me (Ruby 3.0.0, MacOS 12.6) after unsuccessfully trying lots of other suggestions on this page. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using Ventura 13.2.1 and Ruby 3.1.2, only this worked for me:

```
gem install eventmachine -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
```

Comment: this worked for my M1 MacBook running Ventura 13.4 (22F66)

Answer (score 2):

This installed it for me:

```
gem install eventmachine -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1
```

I got it from [the eventmachine Github repo](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/932). Evidently OpenSSL tools were moved / removed from MacOS at some point.

In my case, I wanted to install something else (mailcatcher) with a dependency on eventmachine. I did this by replacing `eventmachine` with `mailcatcher` in the above command.

Answer (score 1):

For Jekyll and Fish:

```
gem install jekyll -- --with-cppflags=-I(brew --prefix openssl)/include
```

Comment: Worked for me, except I had to change `-I(` to `-I$(` - that is, I had to add the `$`. So my full command was `gem install jekyll -- --with-cppflags=-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include`

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, the way to install eventmachine, assuming `brew install openssl` has already installed successfully, is: `gem install eventmachine -- --with-cppflags=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include`

Notice that the include directory has moved.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was:

I had similar eventmachine issues on MAC M1 installing Jekyll. While this is inspired by Stackoverflow running `brew link --force openssl` did NOT solve my issues.

I could solve these Openssl issues as follows:

Run `brew --prefix openssl` to check the openSSL path. If OpenSSL is not installed, install it first.

Run `bundle config build.eventmachine --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl)`.

Run `bundle config build.eventmachine --with-cppflags=-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include`.

Run `bundle`

[Can't install Jekyll - "fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74339443/cant-install-jekyll-fatal-error-openssl-ssl-h-file-not-found/76222201#76222201)

Answer (score 0):

With `openssl@3` with Homebrew it worked by running this command:

```
gem install eventmachine -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin/openssl
```

NOTE the `/bin/openssl` at the end which made the difference for me.