# Bundle install error 'error occurred while installing json (1.7.3)'

Tags: ruby, json, installation, bundle, osx-elcapitan

I am beginner and I can't understand how to fix my error when I try to install Bundle. I'm following the Schneems lessons(currently doing routes_controller_exercise).

Here's my error :

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151101-96612-c518oi.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:158:47: error: too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                          ^
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:793:9: note: macro 'rb_str_new' defined here
#define rb_str_new(str, len) __extension__ (    \
    ^
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:158:11: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long') with an expression of type 'VALUE (const char *, long)' [-Wint-conversion]
VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
      ^        ~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:867:22: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
return *p == '[' && *q == ']' || *p == '{' && *q == '}';
       ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~
generator.c:867:22: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
return *p == '[' && *q == ']' || *p == '{' && *q == '}';
                 ^
       (                     )
generator.c:867:48: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
return *p == '[' && *q == ']' || *p == '{' && *q == '}';
                              ~~ ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:867:48: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
return *p == '[' && *q == ']' || *p == '{' && *q == '}';
                                           ^
                                 (                     )
3 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.7.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/json-1.7.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.7.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have no idea what to do. I'm a beginner so...be nice with me please ! I've been trying many solutions online, but nothing worked so far! I'm using El Capitan 10.11.1.

I've set up Ruby with this link : http://guides.railsgirls.com/install/#virtual-machine.

Doing this exercise now : https://github.com/schneems/routes_controller_exercise

---

## Update:

So I did :

```
bundle update json
```

and it worked until :

```
Installing eventmachine 0.12.10 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151101-99125-1vfqvuu.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling binder.cpp
In file included from binder.cpp:20:
./project.h:103:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/eventmachine-0.12.10/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (0.12.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` succeeds before bundling.
ip-10-0-66-6:routes_controller_exercise Admin$ gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

---

## Solution

Ok so I've uninstall rails and re-install it with the Stanford website.

And now everything's work perfectly! I have no idea what was the problem, but now I install Bundle with no issues.

Comment: It seems the problem isn't with the json gem, but eventmachine. There is already a good solution for installing eventmachine on El Capitan: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818391/gem-eventmachine-fatal-error-openssl-ssl-h-file-not-found

Comment: Thanks, I tried every solutions but I go from json error to eventmachine error. I'm going to reinstall everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One part of the problem is due to a change in `rb_str_new`.

This is a related issue on their GitHub page: https://github.com/flori/json/issues/229

As I understand it, the contributors decided to not fix this since it works as it should in json 1.8.3. It's recommended that you upgrade to that version. The json gem has a very stable API so backwards compatibility is usually not an issue.

If you are using bundler you should go to your `Gemfile` and change version of json to 1.8.3 or higher using `gem 'json', '>=1.8.3'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'm not sure how to edit my **Gemfile**. I only have to open the **Gemfile** in my editor and add : _gem 'json', '>=1.8.3'_ and save it ? Then I run **bundle install** on my terminal? 

In my project directory, I have **Gemfile** and **Gemfile.lock** . In **Gemfile**, I don't see **json** but I do in **Gemfile.lock** (  ** json (1.7.3)**  ). 

I'm new with Ruby so I apologize for the very basic questions.

Comment: I've just added an update of my situation. I think I'm going to cry, I'm so confused.

Comment: @imagirl92 just adding it to your Gemfile as you explained sounds about right. 

It's a great answer for eventmachine here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818391/gem-eventmachine-fatal-error-openssl-ssl-h-file-not-found

If you installed openssl using homebrew (`brew install openssl`), you should be fine just executing `bundle config build.eventmachine --with-cppflags=-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include` and then `bundle install` again.

Comment: If `bundle update json` does not work and if you do not rely on any specific version of a gem that is not specified in your `Gemfile` you can delete `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` again. Then bundler will search for the best available versions for all gems that match the versions defined in `Gemfile`.

Comment: I think it worked @aross ! Thank you. Just to make sure, I have this message at the end (my Ruby version : ruby 2.2.3p173 ) : `Post-install message from rdoc:
Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!`

Comment: @imagirl92 great, you can just ignore that message if you will. Please consider mark my answer as the correct one if you this was the right solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Add gem 'json', '>=1.7.5' and remove Gemfile.lock

then run:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score -1):

In Gemfile you add

> gem 'json', '1.7.3'

after that,

> bundle install

Comment: This will not change anything since the version 1.7.3 is already the version bundler tries to install according to the error message. Using `gem install json -v '1.7.3'` may instead give you additional information to solve the issue or allows you to add additional options to like `--with-opt-dir=[dir]` (`bundle config` can also be used for this).