# Trouble with SSL certificat and eventmachine gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Helle everyone,

I am trying to install the eventmachine gem in a project after it fails during a bundle install.

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.5'
```

Logs:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/studiohb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime()... no
checking for gethrtime()... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling binder.cpp
In file included from binder.cpp:20:
./project.h:116:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/studiohb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@regiex/gems/eventmachine-1.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/studiohb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@regiex/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/eventmachine-1.0.5/gem_make.out
```

So I believe that this is a SSL certificat issue si I tried :

```
brew link --force openssl
```

logs :

```
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
```

Do you guys have any ideas on going around this error ?

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818391/gem-eventmachine-fatal-error-openssl-ssl-h-file-not-found

Comment: Thanks Hang, this command worked :). gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.5' -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib