# Can't install Jekyll - "fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found"

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems, jekyll, bundle

I am attempting to locally host a Jekyll site on Mac OS.
Upon downloading Jekyll with `gem install jekyll` I am met with error:

```
current directory: /Users/main/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20221106-46436-a98sx9 sitelibdir\=./.gem.20221106-46436-a98sx9
compiling binder.cpp
In file included from binder.cpp:20:
./project.h:119:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

I am on MacOS Ventura 13.0.

- `openssl version` returns `LibreSSL 3.3.6`
- `jekyll -v` returns `can't find gem jekyll (>= 0.a) with executable jekyll (Gem::GemNotFoundException)` (obviously)
- `ruby -v` returns `ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin22]`
- `gem -v` returns `3.3.25`
- `bundle -v` returns `Bundler version 2.3.25`
- `rvm list` returns `=* ruby-3.0.0 [ x86_64 ]`
- `gem list` returns

```
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
rubygems-update (3.3.25, 3.0.0)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
```

... among other things. No Ruby version is listed.

I have attempted `brew link --force openssl`, so that I can run `gem install event machine` (with flags), but `brew link --force openssl` returns

```
If you need to have openssl@3 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

I ran that command, re-ran `brew link --force openssl`, and it returned the same error.

What do I do?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar eventmachine issues on M1 Macs installing Jekyll. While this is inspired by [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818391/gem-eventmachine-fatal-error-openssl-ssl-h-file-not-found) running `brew link --force openssl` did NOT solve my issues.

I could solve these Openssl issues as follows:

1. Run `brew --prefix openssl` to check the openSSL path. If OpenSSL is not installed, install it first.
2. Run `bundle config build.eventmachine --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl)`.
3. Run `bundle config build.eventmachine --with-cppflags=-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include`.
4. Run `bundle`

See also this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/932), have you tried to run `brew list openssl` to see if you have different openSSL versions installed?

Comment: I would like to note that upon installing Homebrew, I am not met with the "next steps" and the two commands I see others met with to add Homebrew to path. After following all of your steps, I attempted the first command that others get after installing Homebrew, `echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/main/.zprofile` and nothing was returned. I attempted the second command other users are told to do by console, `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`, and `zsh: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew` is returned.

Comment: Please run the commands above and updated your post with the full bundle install output. Thanks.

Comment: I reset my mac and decided to do my work inside a Docker container. Although it isn't the perfect solution to my problem, it is a perfectly fine work around.
I followed this video by Bill Raymond and all works perfectly and as it should:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owHfKAbJ6_M