# Can't install Puma gem on OSX 10.11.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, puma

I just reformat my MacBook and I try to clone of my Rails project. When I do `bundle install`, Puma gem failed.

When I run `gem install puma -v '2.13.4'`, I get this error:

```
Fetching: puma-2.13.4.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160211-95547-1pdaoaq.rb extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling http11_parser.c
compiling io_buffer.c
io_buffer.c:119:10: warning: passing 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
  return rb_str_new(b->top, b->cur - b->top);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:796:20: note: expanded from macro 'rb_str_new'
        rb_str_new_static((str), (len)) : \
                          ^~~~~
/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:727:37: note: passing argument to parameter here
VALUE rb_str_new_static(const char *, long);
                                    ^
io_buffer.c:119:10: warning: passing 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
  return rb_str_new(b->top, b->cur - b->top);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:797:13: note: expanded from macro 'rb_str_new'
        rb_str_new((str), (len));         \
                   ^~~~~
/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:706:29: note: passing argument to parameter here
VALUE rb_str_new(const char*, long);
                            ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling mini_ssl.c
In file included from mini_ssl.c:3:
/Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warning: use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h" [-W#warnings]
#warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"
 ^
mini_ssl.c:4:10: fatal error: 'openssl/bio.h' file not found
#include <openssl/bio.h>
         ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/zulhilmi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.13.4 for inspection.
```

What should I do?

About my project and my environment:

- Ruby: 2.2.0 (I'm using RVM)
- Rails: 4.2.0
- OSX: 10.11.3

Comment: Looks like you need to install the dependencies like openssl: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143180/puma-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Answer (score 23):

Instead of force linking openssl(which is *NOT* recommended according to this [***Github Opened issue***](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/661)) as proposed by Zulhilmi Zainudin,
I recommend the following solution based on issue 783 of Puma source code(reference below).
I'm using El Capitan (10.11) with openssl installed via Homebrew:

`$ gem install puma -v 2.13.4 -- --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl`

Reference: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/783

But if you want to make it work for all your Gemfiles you can still:

`$ bundle config build.puma --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl`

and confirm:
`$ grep PUMA ~/.bundle/config`

the output should be:

`BUNDLE_BUILD__PUMA: "--with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl"`

Reference: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/718

Answer (score 4):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34871935/1577357) works for me:

```
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
```