# Ruby on rails installation gem puma error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Error:[rake --tasks] /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'puma (~> 3.11)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:254:in`each'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:254:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:48:in`start'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:22:in `resolve'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:258:in`resolve'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:171:in `specs'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:238:in`specs_for'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:227:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in`block in definition_method'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler.rb:107:in`setup'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in`require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in`require'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/RubymineProjects/untitled5/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/RubymineProjects/untitled5/bin/rake:2:in`require_relative'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/RubymineProjects/untitled5/bin/rake:2:in `<main>'
Error:[rake --prereqs] /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in`block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'puma (~> 3.11)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:254:in `each'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:254:in`verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:48:in `start'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:22:in`resolve'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:258:in `resolve'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:171:in`specs'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:238:in `specs_for'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:227:in`requested_specs'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in`setup'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in`'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in`rescue in require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/RubymineProjects/untitled5/config/boot.rb:3:in`'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/RubymineProjects/untitled5/bin/rake:2:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/abhisumishra/RubymineProjects/untitled5/bin/rake:2:in`'
These are the errors I get when trying to install rails. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143180/puma-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension/43174470#43174470

Comment: Also you should edit your question to include: platform and version you are using, what command did you execute to get the error, any other troubleshooting steps you've taken.

Answer (score 0):

I believe installing Ruby Gem puma should solve your problem.

Regards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a minimal answer. It would be more helpful if you provided an explanation along instructions for the installation. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the first line is your error. It looks like you are requiring puma in your code or your gemfile (or...one of the gems you are requiring relies on puma).

You should add puma version 3.11 to your gemfile, then run `bundle-install` to install everything in your gemfile.