# OpenSSL error when starting Rails local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I just cloned a repo, and can't even get to run a local server on my machine. Other co-workers said they had no problem, so I assume there's something wrong with my enviroment.

```
$ bundle exec rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
/home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/ruby: symbol lookup error: /home/fran/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/puma_http11.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_ssl
```

I already tried installing ruby 2.6.5 with my openssl dir like this:

```
$ RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=/usr/lib/ssl" rbenv install  2.6.5
```

But the problem persists.

Any hint on this error? Never happened to me before.

Comment: Does `gem uninstall puma; gem install puma -v '4.3.1' -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/lib/ssl; bundle install; bundle exec rails s` work?

Comment: Yes! This worked! What are those `cppflags`?

Comment: Puma's your web server, it needs to know where your OpenSSL libs are when it compiles. That's all the flags do.

Comment: There is an existing question with the answer I provided, since it worked I recommend deleting your question: [puma gem - Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143180/puma-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Comment: @anothermh But the error message is different there as far as I can tell. Someone having the same issue as op wouldn't be able to find it if he searched for an answer and he would have to open another question. Wouldn't it make more sense for you to post the command as an answer or mark this question as duplicate referring to the question you linked?

Comment: If you find yourself adding flags to install a gem, then once you have them right, you can (should?) add those into your `~/.bundle/config` file.

Comment: Fair points @Viktor!